# What is the process to raise a complaint to the manager at the check-in counter?

Tags: air-travel, check-in, qatar-airways, sfo

From my understanding, the hierarchy at the check-in counter is base employee < supervisor < manager.  The supervisor is typically around the check-in counter, but I don't know about the manager. What is the process to raise a complaint to the manager at the check-in counter, regarding some issues that happened at the check-in counter? Assume that the supervisor refuses to connect to the manager.

If specific to the airline, I'm currently interested in Qatar Airways. If specific to the airport, I'm currently interested in SFO.

Comment: If you've raised your complaint with everyone who is willing to speak to you at the airport and someone has said it's the final word and there's nobody above them you can speak to, I'm not sure what further process you're looking for beyond trying to contact the airline and complain after the fact. There's no law that requires them to keep bringing higher ranked authorities to the counter.

Comment: @ZachLipton Got it, I was hoping that some manager would be at the back office at the airport (if not around the check-in counter), and if so, that the supervisor would be supposed to give me some way to contact them upon request (I did hear that the manager had been reached by phone for another passenger issue). But perhaps there is no such policy and that indeed it is up to the passenger to find a way to contact the customer support if the check-in supervisor is unhelpful. Just trying to understand the proper + efficient way to file for a complaint.

Comment: Out of a base or hub, there is often very little staff from the airline, possibly no staff at all. Airlines don't keep a full staff for just a flight a day, for instance. They usually outsource this to a local handling company (sometimes the airport or one of its subsidiaries, or often one of the global ground services companies like Swissport). There's probably just a station manager who is actually an employee of the airline, and possibly not even that. Call customer service. If you have status, call the premium hotline (on the back of your FF card if you have it).

Comment: Ticket sales have "more power" on company computer systems. so I expect if there is a manager, it will be there. But as other comments: often you should call them (I would not expect manager (if he is on such airport) will speak with you: they have to coordinate much things (problems with arriving baggage, crew, dispatchers, signing bills, etc.)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks, interesting trick!

Comment: Related: [Qatar Airways canceled the flight, but I cannot get a refund. What can I do?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/162889/13107)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize the answers the question received in the comments: 1)  There's no law that requires them to keep bringing higher-ranked authorities to the counter 2) Out of a base or hub, there is often very little staff from the airline, possibly no staff at all. 3) Ticket sales have "more power" on company computer systems. so if there is a manager, they likely will be there. 4) if no manager can be found, simply contact the airline and complain after the fact.

> - contact the airline and complain after the fact. There's no law that requires them to keep bringing higher-ranked authorities to the counter. – [Zach Lipton](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton) [Mar 10 at 6:14](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162808/what-is-the-process-to-raise-a-complaint-to-the-manager-at-the-check-in-counter#comment408080_162808)
> - Out of a base or hub, there is often very little staff from the airline, possibly no staff at all. Airlines don't keep a full staff for just a flight a day, for instance. They usually outsource this to a local handling company (sometimes the airport or one of its subsidiaries, or often one of the global ground services companies like Swissport). There's probably just a station manager who is actually an employee of the airline, and possibly not even that. Call customer service. If you have status, call the premium hotline (on the back of your FF card if you have it). – [jcaron](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30703/jcaron) [Mar 10 at 8:59](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162808/what-is-the-process-to-raise-a-complaint-to-the-manager-at-the-check-in-counter#comment408082_162808)
> - Ticket sales have "more power" on company computer systems. so I expect if there is a manager, it will be there. But as other comments: often you should call them (I would not expect manager (if he is on such airport) will speak with you: they have to coordinate much things (problems with arriving baggage, crew, dispatchers, signing bills, etc.) – [Giacomo Catenazzi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/53544/giacomo-catenazzi) [Mar 10 at 9:59](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162808/what-is-the-process-to-raise-a-complaint-to-the-manager-at-the-check-in-counter#comment408086_162808)